# Thread pool using same object

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I created a thread pool where each thread takes an object from a queue and handles it. I'm not sure I implemented it in the right way. Here's the code:

```
public class HandlerThreadsPool<T> {

private BlockingQueue<T> queue;
private IQueueObjectHandler<T> objectHandler;

private class ThreadClass implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
                objectHandler.handleItem(queue.take());
        }
    }
}

public HandlerThreadsPool(int numberOfThreads, BlockingQueue<T> queue, IQueueObjectHandler<T> dataHandler){

        this.queue = queue;
        this.objectHandler = dataHandler;
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
                service.execute(new ThreadClass());
        service.shutdown();
}

}
```

The dataHandler handles the object doing some stuff. Is it correct in this way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At first it is not a good practice to create, submit to and shutdown `ExecutorService` inside constructor.
Look at [shutdown() javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown())

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are
>   executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no
>   additional effect if already shut down.

You didn't post `IQueueObjectHandler`, but it seems for me that your ThreadClass jobs will run infinitely, off course if you are not stopping them by explicitly throwing some unchecked exception inside `objectHandler.handleItem(..)` which would be wrong. And you can have problems with JVM termination because of these infinitely running not daemon threads. ([JVM graceful termination conditions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)) 

Also you don't catch `InterruptedException` while executing `queue.take()`, this would cause a compile time error. Handling `InterruptedException` properly would help you to stop on possible `shutdownNow()`.

So

- Don't shutdown pool in constructor, this will lead to problems. Use [Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(..)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) if you don't want to make shutdown somewhere else.
- Use `shutdownNow()` to actually stop executor's threads, if they are in infinite loops, handle `InterruptedException` inside `ThreadClass` for this. Or you can stop them using `volatile boolean` or `AtomicBoolean` flag which indicates status, running/stopped. Check flag in the loop and change it to `false` whenever you need to shutdown jobs.
- Make `ExecutorService service` an instance variable, not local. Loosing reference to running `ExecutorService` looks bad. This can help you somewhere else.